# How Can I Access Self Signed Certificates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, openssl, macos-sierra

Note: I'm a Mac person and only use the Windows 10 laptop to test responsive web code for my websites. The last time I regularly used Windows was XP almost ten years ago.

On my Mac mini Server (development) I created OpenSSL certificates and a CA using SHA256. I also added the websites using SSL to /etc/hosts in Apache 2.4.25. Everything is working as expected.

I have done web searches trying to find information on how to get this to work. Several links said that if I went to Tools-->Internet Options and add the URL to Trusted Sites that should take care of it. I guess that worked for earlier versions of IE but I could not get it working on my Windows 10 laptop. I have the latest versions of IE and Edge installed.

After several hours of searching I saw this link that stated I could add certificates to Windows Certificates Snap-In.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108168/using-self-sign-certificate-in-internet

This link shows how to use the MMC Snap-in. I did these steps for the Local computer.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632619.aspx

The following link shows how to view certificates.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx

I created a p7b file with my public root CA and certificates, copied to the laptop and imported the file using the steps in the link below.

http://www.databasemart.com/howto/SQLoverssl/How_To_Import_Personal_Certificate_With_MMC.aspx

Internet Explorer still does not find the security certificate, even after adding the link to Trusted Sites. How do I get this working? These are test domains that will not be used by anyone but me. I just need to get these websites to display on my Windows Laptop for testing purposes.

Comment: IE will display the certificate and the reason it doesn't trust it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I realized that when I followed the instructions on the last link that I had put my certificates in Personal. I imported the file into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder. My websites display somewhat. Sometimes they display and sometimes they don't. Not sure why at this point. They are test websites. If it gets too annoying I will test those websites in Heroku on the Windows laptop.